# how do i use a changeable value in a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

it's pretty hard to explain, but I know why what I tried doesn't work I just want to know if there is a solution. I hope you can understand what I want to do through the code

```
async function copyInvite() {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.rl-btn-invite");

    addEventListenerLoop(buttons, 'click', event => { navigator.clipboard.writeText(node.id); });
}



async function addEventListenerLoop(nodes, type, code) {
    for (const node of nodes) {
        node.addEventListener(type, code);
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a value in the function change based on what node I am doing it on

I tried using mutable values but it either didn't work or I didn't try well enough.

Answer (score 2):

Given your example, the simplest solution would be to use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of `node` to refer to the element the handler was bound to:

```
addEventListenerLoop(
  buttons,
  'click',
  event => { navigator.clipboard.writeText(event.currentTarget.id); }
  //                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you are looking for a solution to have access to the current `node` in your `code` callback.

For this, you can try to nest your callback methods, where the outer one receives the current `node` and returns the actual event handler for this specific `node`.

This will look like this:

```
async function copyInvite() {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.rl-btn-invite");

    addEventListenerLoop(buttons, 'click', node => event => { navigator.clipboard.writeText(node.id); });
}


async function addEventListenerLoop(nodes, type, code) {
    for (const node of nodes) {
        node.addEventListener(type, code(node));
    }
}
```